# Multiple Datatables on dynamic tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

i have developed a dynamic tab mechanism for my web application that any internal content will load using ajax in a new tab which will be appended at the last active tab something like tab functionality in browsers for executing loaded content js i simply have a namespace custom html5 data tag witch is the name of the script and i execute the init() method of it when a new tab is created, it works well on simple jquery scripts but when i try to load pages with jQuery Datatable in them which i'm using for reports my report filter form only works on the last datatable, i have no idea how to solve this issue, here is my tabs.js and reports.js code the second one is the Datatable javascripts.

tabs.js:

```
(function() {

// open e new tab:
var tabs_label = 1;
var tab_id = 1;
var tabs_num = 1;
var defaults_open = false;
var reports_open = false;
var ns ;//needs change
$('.tab-link').live('click',function(e) {
    var parent = $(this);

    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if (href == '/defaults/' && defaults_open){
        e.preventDefault();
        bootbox.alert('تب تعریف پیش فرض ها باز می باشد!');

    }
    // else if(href == '/report/' && reports_open){
    //  e.preventDefault();
    //  bootbox.alert('تب گزارش ها باز می باشد');

    // }
    else{

        var tab_name = $(this).attr('data-name');
        e.preventDefault();
        tab_id ++;
        if (tabs_num > 6) {
            bootbox.alert('تب های باز شده بیش از حد مجاز است.');

        }
        else {
        $('.tab-pane').filter('.active').removeClass('active');
        $.blockUI({ message: $('#wait-icon'), css: {width: '64px',      height: '64px' }});
        var content = $('<div></div>', {
        class:"tab-pane dynamic-tab active",
        id:tab_id,
         });
        content.appendTo('div#main-tabs');
        $('ul.nav-tabs li.active').removeClass('active');
        var new_li = $("<li class='active' data-type='"+href+"'><a style='float:left' class='tabbtn' href="+tab_id+" data-toggle='tab'>"+tabs_label+" - "+tab_name+"</a><a style='float:right' class='close' id='tabClose'><i class='icon-remove'></i></a></li>")
        new_li.appendTo('ul#tabs');
        content.load( href + ' div#arya', function(response, status, xhr) {
            if(parent.attr('namespace')){
                ns = eval(parent.attr('namespace'));
                if(ns.root){
                    ns.root = content;
                }
                ns.init();
            }
            $.unblockUI();
            if(status == 'error'){
                bootbox.alert("در حال حاضر سرور با مشکل مواجه است", "خروج",   function(){
                    new_li.find("a.close").trigger('click');
                });

            }

        });
        tabs_num++;
        tabs_label++;
        if(href == '/defaults/'){
            defaults_open = true;
        }
        else if(href == '/report/'){
            reports_open = true;
        }
        }
    }
});// sell tab name needs work.

// tab activatior function

$('#tabs a.tabbtn').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    var selector = 'div#' + id;
    $('.dynamic-tab').filter('.active').removeClass('active');
    var new_tab = $('.dynamic-tab').filter(selector);
    new_tab.addClass('active');
    console.log(new_tab);
    ns.root = new_tab;

});

// close a tab:

$('a#tabClose').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $this = $(this);
    var a = $this.siblings('a');
    var li = $this.parent();
    console.log(li);
    if(li.attr('data-type') == '/defaults/'){
        defaults_open = false;
    }
    else if(li.attr('data-type') == '/report/'){
        reports_open = false;
    }
    var id = a.attr('href');
    var div = $('div#' + id);
    if (div.hasClass('active')){
        var last = div.siblings('div.tab-pane').last();
        last.addClass('active');
        ns.root = last;
    }
    div.detach();
    var li = a.parent();
    if (li.siblings('.active').length == 0){
        li.siblings('li').last().addClass('active');    
    }
    li.detach();
    tabs_num--;
    tabs_label--;
});

})();
```

reports.js:

```
var reports = {
'root': $('.tab-pane#defaults_init'),
'table_init': function() {
    var oTable;
  $.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnReloadAjax = function ( oSettings, sNewSource ) {
    if ( typeof sNewSource != 'undefined' )
    oSettings.sAjaxSource = sNewSource;
    console.log($(this));

    this.fnClearTable( this );

    this.oApi._fnProcessingDisplay( oSettings, true );
    var that = this;
    var myData = new Array({ "name": "name", "value": reports.root.find('#name').val()}, { "name": "family", "value": reports.root.find('#family').val()}, { "name": "national_id", "value": reports.root.find('#national_id').val()}, { "name": "city", "value": reports.root.find('#city').val()}, { "name": "job", "value": reports.root.find('#job').val()}, { "name": "date_from", "value": reports.root.find('#date_from').val()}, { "name": "date_to", "value": reports.root.find('#date_to').val()}, { "name": "age_from", "value": reports.root.find('#age_from').val()}, { "name": "age_to", "value": reports.root.find('#age_to').val()}, { "name": "credit_from", "value": reports.root.find('#credit_from').val()}, { "name": "credit_to", "value": reports.root.find('#credit_to').val()}); 
    $.ajax({
      url: oSettings.sAjaxSource,
      dataType: 'json',
      data: myData,
      type: "POST",
      success: function(json) {
        /* Got the data - add it to the table */
        for ( var i=0 ; i<json.aaData.length ; i++ ) {
        that.oApi._fnAddData( oSettings, json.aaData[i] );
        }

        oSettings.aiDisplay = oSettings.aiDisplayMaster.slice();
        that.fnDraw( that );
        that.oApi._fnProcessingDisplay( oSettings, false );
        }
    });
}
},
'init': function(){


    oTable = reports.root.find('.targetTable').dataTable( {
      "sDom": "<'row-fluid'r<'span12'l>>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'p><'span6'i>>",
      "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
      "oLanguage": {
                  "sUrl": "/media/translation/dataTables.persian.txt"
              },
      "sAjaxSource": "/report/ajax/customers/",
      "sServerMethod": "POST",
      "bDestroy": true,
      // "bRetrieve": true,
      "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
          aoData.push( { "name": "name", "value": reports.root.find('#name').val()} );
          aoData.push( { "name": "family", "value": reports.root.find('#family').val()});
          aoData.push( { "name": "national_id", "value": reports.root.find('#national_id').val()} );
          aoData.push( { "name": "city", "value": reports.root.find('#city').val()} );
          aoData.push( { "name": "job", "value": reports.root.find('#job').val()} );
          aoData.push( { "name": "date_from", "value": reports.root.find('#date_from').val()} );
          aoData.push( { "name": "date_to", "value": reports.root.find('#date_to').val()} );
          aoData.push( { "name": "age_from", "value": reports.root.find('#age_from').val()} );
          aoData.push( { "name": "age_to", "value": reports.root.find('#age_to').val()} );
          aoData.push( { "name": "credit_from", "value": reports.root.find('#credit_from').val()} );
          aoData.push( { "name": "credit_to", "value": reports.root.find('#credit_to').val()} );
          console.log(aoData);
      },
      "aoColumns": [
        { "mDataProp": "name" },
        { "mDataProp": "family" },
        { "mDataProp": "national_id" },
        { "mDataProp": "birthday" ,"bSearchable": false, "bVisible": false},
        { "mDataProp": "phone" ,"bSearchable": false, "bVisible": false},
        { "mDataProp": "cellphone" ,"bSearchable": false, "bVisible": false},
        { "mDataProp": "email" ,"bSearchable": false, "bVisible": false},
        { "mDataProp": "city" ,"bSearchable": false, "bVisible": false},
        { "mDataProp": "country" ,"bSearchable": false, "bVisible": false},
        { "mDataProp": "address" ,"bSearchable": false, "bVisible": false},
        { "mDataProp": "job" },
        { "mDataProp": "credit" ,"bSearchable": false, "bVisible": false},
        { "mDataProp": "age" ,"bSearchable": false, "bVisible": false},
        { "mDataProp": "creation_time" ,"bSearchable": false, "bVisible": false},
    ],
    } );
    /* Add a click handler to the rows - this could be used as a callback */

    $('#targetTable tbody tr').live('click', function () {
      var aData = oTable.fnGetData( this );
      infoTpl = "<div class='row-fluid span12'><table class='table table-striped'><tbody>";
      infoTpl += "<tr><td>نام: <span>"+aData['name']+"</span></td><td>نام خانوادگی: <span>"+aData['family']+"</span></td><td>کد ملی: <span>"+aData['national_id']+"</span></td><td>تاریخ تولد: <span>"+aData['birthday']+"</span></td></tr>";
      infoTpl += "<tr><td>تلفن: <span>"+aData['phone']+"</span></td><td>تلفن همراه: <span>"+aData['cellphone']+"</span></td><td colspan='2'>ایمیل: <span>"+aData['email']+"</span></td></tr>";
      infoTpl += "<tr><td colspan='2'>آدرس: <span>"+aData['address']+"</span></td><td>شهر: <span>"+aData['city']+"</span></td><td>کشور: <span>"+aData['country']+"</span></td></tr>";
      infoTpl += "<tr><td>سن: <span>"+aData['age']+"</span></td><td>میزان اعتبار: <span>"+aData['credit']+"</span></td><td>تاریخ ایجاد در سیستم: <span>"+aData['creation_time']+"</span></td></tr>";
      infoTpl += "</tbody></table></div>";
      reports.root.find('#targetInfo').html(infoTpl);
      reports.root.find('#targetInfo > div > table > tbody > tr > td > span').css("color","navy");
      $(this).toggleClass('row_selected');
    } );

    reports.root.find('#queryForm').submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
        oTable.fnReloadAjax();
        return false;
    });





},
};
$(document).ready(function () {
    reports.table_init();
});
```

Comment: Two things: change `.live()` to `.on()` as live is deprecated; could you explain what do you mean by last? The last one loaded, the last one on the list etc. Also if you paste into jsFiddle that would be nice.

Comment: yes i mean the last one loaded. thanks.

Comment: I think you are using the same variable `oTable` for every table and that's why the only last one gets loaded.

Comment: yes the problem is every time the same variable is revalued, i don't know what to do because i have to load same content multiple times to the page, is there any way so these variables work independently, maybe with scopes or something, i have no clear idea, any idea?